# What is Zeitgeist Data Hub background process?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, 22.10, background-process

I am running Ubuntu MATE 22.10. I noticed the background process `zeitgeist-datahub` in `htop`. What is this process doing? Can I safely disable it?

I found a package of the same name. https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/zeitgeist

This the output of `apt rdepends zeitgeist`.

```
$ apt rdepends zeitgeist
zeitgeist
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: activity-log-manager (>= 0.8~)
 |Recommends: synapse
  Depends: python3-zeitgeist
  Suggests: libzeitgeist-2.0-0
 |Recommends: libzeitgeist-1.0-1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Zeitgeist webpage](https://zeitgeist.freedesktop.org/):

> ##### Providing Desktop Activity Awareness
>
> Zeitgeist is a service which logs the users’s activities and events, anywhere from files opened to
> websites visited and conversations.
>
> It makes this information readily available for other applications to
> use.
>
> It is able to establish relationships between items based on
> similarity and usage patterns.

You could see which other applications use this package (reverse dependencies):

```
apt rdepends zeitgeist
```

Since it's a service about usage tracking, it should be safe to disable.

Zeitgeist-datahub places the following link: `/etc/xdg/autostart/zeitgeist-datahub.desktop`. Move this file away from the autostart folder to disable it.

Also, you can disable the `zeitgeist-core` service:

```
sudo systemctl stop zeitgeist.service
sudo systemctl disable zeitgeist.service
```

And if you want to go all in:

```
sudo systemctl mask zeitgeist.service
```

Comment: How to disable it?